# Integers are marked as dirty attributes no matter what

Tags: yii2

I need to check if a model has been updated and what attributes have changed when saving.

I'm using dirtyAttributes and filter `intval` as the [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#dirty-attributes) suggests.
The values are coming from an API and are type-cast as they come in, so in theory the filter is redundant.

**Model rules**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['contract_date', 'order_date'], 'integer'],
        [['contract_date', 'order_date'], 'filter', 'filter' => 'intval'],
    ];
}
```

**This is some of the code currently running:**

```
// Add the changed status variables to the job log
$dirty_attributes = array_keys($model->dirtyAttributes);
if($model->save()) foreach ($dirty_attributes as $attribute)
{
    $data[$attribute] = $model->getOldAttribute($attribute).' ('.gettype($model->getOldAttribute($attribute)).')'. ' => '. $model->$attribute.' ('.gettype($model->$attribute).')';
}
var_dump($data);
```

**This produces:**

```
["contract_date"]=>
string(44) "1559669638 (integer) => 1559669638 (integer)"
["order_date"]=>
string(44) "1559669638 (integer) => 1559669638 (integer)"
```

There is probably something obvious I'm missing, but I can understand what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After saving model all "oldAttributes" are updated to store new values so comparing them like you do makes no sense. If you want to check which attributes have been changed after saving you can override `afterSave()` method in your model like:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    // $changedAttributes -> this is it
    parent::afterSave(); // call parent to trigger event
}
```

or listen for `ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_INSERT` / `ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE` event where this data is also passed.

Comment: That is a good point, and it makes perfect sense. Regardless, the main issue right now is that they are in fact marked as dirty (notice i extract the attribute names before the save). All attributes of the model (21) are integers, but only four of them behave this way.

Comment: That's weird... Could you show API response and the code responsible for type casting?

Comment: I solved it. This was a weird one. I must have been tired. Combined with your comment, and the fact that i cast a date('Y-m-d') to timestamp without specifying the 'H:i:s' and the intval that messed with my null-values this was just a big pile of late-night workings. Thank you for your help.